# Sending a Push Notification from one user to another user with Parse?

Tags: android, parse-platform

hi I am very new on parse.com

I have downloaded android sdk and install my phone. When I create notification on dashboard it works.

But How can I send one user to another user? I dont find any examples.Is it possible?(i think it is possible bu I do not succeed)

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want to send a Push notification to a specific user either you can query 
the Installation table or you can use the channel. So if you use channel then you must specify 
unique channel for each user. Then you can use the below code to send a push;

```
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
String yourMessage = "Hello World";
push.setChannel("your user channel name");
push.setMessage(yourMessage);
push.sendInBackground();
```

Hope this helps,
Regards.

Comment: thanks for answering, how can I use channel for every user? it is on parse.com ? which one is safety and easy to use?

Comment: As far as I know this is not a Parse property. Actually, channels are used for broadcasting information.However, when you enable push notification, you can set the user object id(you can be sure this is unique) as channel identifier and use it as user specific channel. You can use PushService.subscribe to make user subscribe a channel.

Comment: I also want to mention that you can use the advanced targeting mechanism where you can query the installation table and send y push to your specified target.

Comment: think I have 2 android phone , and I give their device id (it is unique , for example first device has 1 device id and second device has 2 device id) so If I want to sent hello world to first to second I use your code and channel name should be 2 right?

Comment: Also check the Parse web site client push enabled is on. Then you can use the code that I provide.

Comment: thanks it is working, last thing I want to ask, when I send notifications, it has always same title "ParseStarterProject" and same icon. please help about this how can I modify that

Comment: Parse notification accepts JSON string where you can customize the Push notification. You can use the title reserved field to change the title.Hope this helps.

Comment: please look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24730920/how-can-i-get-data-or-title-from-receiving-notifications