# How can I get data or title from receiving notifications?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I create simple "ParseStarterProject" as default of **parse.com** project. It works. I send notification from one device to other device successfully via setchannel method.

But the problem is  I do not use receiver class(I do not know how can I use that) so when a notification comes I need to get its message ? it is possible? or if I use set data can I get its data ?

### I use this code to send message:

```
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
String yourMessage = "Selam from LG G2";//I want to get this message from other device?
push.setChannel("device2");
push.setMessage(yourMessage);
//push.setData("exampledata"); if I use this can I get this data from other device?
push.sendInBackground();
```

### my manifest file:

```
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

        <!--
          IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
        -->
        <category android:name="com.parse.starter" />
      </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class that extends `BroadcastReceiver`, here we call it `MyCustomReceiver`. Declare the usage of this receiver in your manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.MyCustomReceiver" android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.example.UPDATE_STATUS" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I'm not sure what you mean by you have problems with "MyCustomReceiver class on the main activity", in your comment to @kingspeech's answer.

---

In the worst case, you can create your own Receiver which extends the ParseBroadcastReceiver (and reference the extended class in the manifest). Then it should work by default, but you'll be able to hook into `onReceive(Context, Intent)`

Comment: the code you'd add to the receiver is already given in your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24727055/494879) (not sure why you opened a second one for the same issue)

Comment: @Ersin It'd be helpful if you can comment to say why you selected this as the answer (which part was helpful) because then this and the question can be cleaned up to make it more useful to others.

Answer (score 1):

As Parse tutorial directs, you ca use JSONObject to set data and you can put whatever you want.
Then when you receive Push notification you can have a access to read the previously prepared JSONObject. Please look at the Android tutorial https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#options/Android.

Hope this helps,
Regards.

Comment: I have problems MyCustomReceiver(in the manifest) and MyCustomReceiver lass on the main activity. They do not response :( I use default receiver. I update my question now please look at it. thanks

Comment: it help me a lot. when I use json to push notification, how can I subscribe my channel?

Comment: you can use the ParseInstallation object to specify the channel. The class references is https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseInstallation.html